# get last 5 minutes log from log file with search string

Tags: bash, shell, date

We have 2 different Log file format,

```
1.
Some strings : 20200429 064351 Name : server Error
```

```
2.
ERROR       Error Message
TIME        Wed Apr 29 11:36:39 2020
Release     123
```

I have tried below command to automatically get the last 5 minutes log content from log file.

```
sed -n "/ $(date +\%R -d "-5 min")/,$"p logfile.log | grep "ERROR"
```

but it doesn't worked.

Same command tried with different log file and its worked.
Working log file format

```
29.04.2020 00:00:08 some string.
```

Any Solution ?

Comment: time format is different, so you should delete ":". try with token=$(date +\%R -d "-5 min" | tr -d :) and sed -n "/ $token/,$"p logfile | grep "ERROR"

Comment: Thanks...
If my log format is like below.(Don't know it is space or tab in between TIME and Date)

TIME        Wed Apr 29 11:36:39 2020

Comment: It is not clear to me: what is the format of your log file finally? Please edit your question and give a real sample with a few lines, hiding the sensitive information if necessary.

Comment: For first log file its worked with token=$(date +\%R -d "-5 min" | tr -d :) and sed -n "/ $token/,$"p logfile | grep "ERROR".... Need solution for second log file

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems in your script:

a) `sed` as you invoke it will print all the input lines at least once and the last lines twice; you can fix that by executing `sed -e "/$pattern/,\$p" -e "d" logfile.log`, adding the arguments `-e d` at the end of your options before the file name;

b) the time returned with the `%R` option contains `:` that are not present your logfile; you can fix this by using the date format `+'%Y%M%d %H%M'`;

c) The string you are looking for is `Error` but you give `ERROR` as argument to `grep`, which is not going to work since `grep` arguments are case sensitive by default.

Try:

```sh
pattern=$(date +'%Y%M%d %H%M' -d '-5 minutes')
sed -e "/: \*\*$pattern/,\$p"  -e "d" logfile.log | grep "Error"
```

But it is simplier to issue everything from `sed`, without `grep`:

```sh
pattern=$(date +'%Y%M%d %H%M' -d '-5 minutes')
sed -e "/: \*\*$pattern/,\${/Error/p}" -e "d" logfile.log
```

Comment: Expect a more elegant solution in AWK. I leave this to others.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed -n "/^$(date --date='5 minutes ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')/,\$p" <log location> | grep error
```

Make sure to check your log file date and time format. Can edit `+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M` with log file.